# sliding active element background for navigation

Tags: jquery, html, css, navigation

I want to make a sliding background for the active element of the navigation, like the one in the below given website.

```
http://www.exosource.com/en/
```

[image]

Don't know how its done with css and jquery. Can some one help me with this please.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All the answers here are for the sliders (banners).

And I suppose your problem is the sliding background in navigation options.

If that is so, the following link will definitely help you out.

http://css-tricks.com/jquery-magicline-navigation/

Thanks

Comment: And, here is a fiddle for that

<http://jsfiddle.net/DJDavid98/bUYuf/3/>

Comment: Thanks alot @Manik Arora

Answer (score 0):

Try using Bxslider jquery plugin [Link](http://bxslider.com/)
Please note that this is :

1. Fully responsive - will adapt to any device
2. Horizontal, vertical, and fade modes Slides
3. can contain images, video, or HTML content
4. Advanced touch / swipe support built-in
5. Uses CSS transitions for slide animation (native hardware acceleration!)
6. Full callback API and public methods
7. Small file size, fully themed, simple to implement
8. Browser support: Firefox, Chrome, Safari, iOS, Android,IE7+

Comment: I want the menu effect not the page effect @DhruvJoshi